# Is 'an eye' a designator?

Tags: logic, homework

I realize this may be a super-rookie question, but I have to ask. It is in connection with my logic module.

Is 'an eye' in this sentence a designator?

> I was told to keep an eye on him

I know "I" and "Him" are designators, but is "an eye"? I mean, it is not a specific thing it refers to, only some eye ... or is this wrong?

Comment: I think this question is about formal logic, and I believe "designator" is a technical rather than grammatical term as used here.  Maybe try philosophy.se?

Comment: Whatever *designator* even means, I guess the answer is that *an eye* is not a designator. It is not anything. "Keep an eye" is an idiom; a single unit. You must not break it up in parts. There *are* no parts. You might as well try and analyze what role the "old" plays in "told".

Comment: Trombone, as I understand your question, "I" and "him" are rigid designators and "eye" is a flaccid designator, but I so little expertise in the phylosophy of language that it takes me two tries to spell philosoophy.

Comment: If this is from logic, there should be a formal definition of a `designator`. This sounds to me like a term in a particular theory, rather than a standard term. Most logicians and linguists talk about _reference_ and related terms. Unless the module is using _designator_ to mean 'referential NP' or some such. Is it distinguished by being third person? Or not deictic? Or what? [Logic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) is a calculus and calculi need complete definitions.

Comment: @MichaelOwenSartin: I really like your designation inflation theoretical model; the only problem is how to pronounce _flaccid_. I propose we all **say** that it's a _flaksid designator_ (the more refined will no doubt say _flax seed_); this seems preferable to making it rhyme with _acid_.

Comment: @JohnLawler We do have a definiton of designator: 'A designator is a word or phrase which can be used to refer to a single thing, where 'thing' is taken broadly, f.ex: proper names, non-count nouns (like water, beauty, etc.), singular personal pronous, and definite descriptions'. That is what our online text book says, at least. Our excericise is to analyze sentences into Designators and Predicates. I may have trouble with this sentence simply because since I am not fluent in English .. 'An eye' (in my head) seems to refer to something but not a specific thing, if that makes any sense at all.

Comment: Then it means 'referential NP', and seems to include metaphors as well as real objects. And it seems to include deitic pronouns as well as referentials. I'd say it's better to go with the basic terms: `Predicate`, `Argument`.

Comment: meta: What is with the "homework" tag? I thought homework questions are OT.

Answer (score 1):

With no authority, and given the definitions above, I'd be inclined to say that 'an eye' is not a designator. 'To keep an eye on' is a phrase which means to 'watch', 'observe' or 'pay attention to'. You could just as easily re-phrase your sentence to:

```
I was told to watch him
```